# Collision detection not working in Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, phaser, html

I am new to phaser. So I started working on a game but I am stuck at implementing collision detection. I want to do it between a static group(dot) and a Sprite(obs).

```
function create(){
```

`dot = this.physics.add.staticGroup(dotx, doty, 'dot');  

dot.create(dotx, doty, 'dot');

obs = this.physics.add.sprite(obsX, obsY, 'obs');

this.physics.add.collider(obs, ball, alert, null, this);`

}

Comment: How does your current code behave? How does this differ from how you want it to behave?

Comment: Currently the code shows no error but when I run the game the objects pass over each other without the collision detection taking place.